# Redirect Visitors Based on coming from website in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Is it possible to redirect visitors based on coming from website in WordPress

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. If I understand correctly you're trying to redirect base on a specific referer.

`$_SERVER` let you retrieve server and execution environment information. It is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations.

`$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` enable you to retrieve the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERER` as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

```
<?= $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]; ?>
```

- Source @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php